# Facebook : share a flash player through JS API and Open Graph tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to share a flash player on Facebook using Open Graph API and the Facebook JS API. I do it this way :

```
FB.ui(
{
    method      : 'feed',
    link        : theUrl[0],

    // OR

    method      : 'share',
    href        : theUrl[0],

},
function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        // alert('Shared !');
    } else {
        // alert('An error occured. Your link has not been shared...');
    }
});
```

and

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Believe Digital Player">
<meta property="og:url" content="URL">
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE">
<meta property="og:type" content="video">
<meta property="og:image" content="IMAGE">
<meta property="og:video" content="SWF_PATH"/>
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="S_SWF_PATH"/>
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="400">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="400">
```

When I share my link directly on Facebook everything is ok.
But when i use the JS button I have created to do the same in my app, all open graphs tags are correctly matched except og:video and og:video:secured_url. The result is that the link is posted on my wall but it acts like it is not a video player so when I click it I'm redirected to my website

I have found another way to do the same (but it doesn't work on mobile phones, the popup is empty '-_-) :

```
var paramUrl = {'p' : {'url' : theUrl[0]}};
var urlFb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?"+$.param(paramUrl);
window.open(urlFb, "", "menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=500, height=430");
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you link to your page? Have you tried to debug the url using https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by modifying the url of the :

```
var paramUrl = {'p' : {'url' : theUrl}};
var urlFb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?"+$.param(paramUrl);
window.open(urlFb, "", "menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=500, height=430");
```

becomes

```
var paramUrl = {'u' : theUrl};
var urlFb = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?"+$.param(paramUrl);
window.open(urlFb, "", "menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=no, menubar=no, width=500, height=430");
```

And it works fine.